# Is it possible to get the current item number and perform arithmetic on it in enumerate environment?

Tags: environments, enumerate, itemize

That is, suppose that I am at item `n` and I want to make a reference to item `n - 3` without explicitly specifying it.

Comment: `\label` item n-3 and `\ref` it. Probably you should clarify better your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
    \item \number\numexpr\value{enumi}-3\relax
```

Here's a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item cow
    \item lion
    \item moo
    \item \number\numexpr\value{enumi}-3\relax
    \item meow
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need `\relax` after the calculation?