# Chapter count not increasing

Tags: chapters, etoolbox

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{totchapters}

\providecommand\totchap{}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocounter{totchapters}{\value{chapter}}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\gdef\string\totchap{\number\value{totchapters}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocounter{totchapters}{\value{chapter}}\setcounter{chapter}{0}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\totchap    \chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to gain access to the total number of chapters in a document. I got inspiration from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55583/10898. But for some reason or the other the chapter counter is affected and no longer increasing. Why is that the case and how can it be fixed? Note that I would like to use this total to make calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the code to use `\stepcounter{totchapters}` rather than

```
\addtocounter{totchapters}{\value{chapter}}
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood the original intent, but here's a complete MWE that works as expected

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{totchapters}

\providecommand\totchap{}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  %\stepcounter{totchapters}%
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\gdef\string\totchap{\number\value{totchapters}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\stepcounter{totchapters}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\totchap\
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use `\totchap` in calculations? For example, `5/\totchap`.

Comment: @azetina [Is it possible to get the current item number and perform arithmetic on it in enumerate environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100927)

Comment: Something like `\number\numexpr\totchap+3\relax` I suppose.

Comment: Why using a new counter? Doesn't `\immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\string\totchap{\number\value{chapter}}` do the same?

Answer (score 6):

The `totcount` does this without any redefinition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}

\begin{document}
This document has \total{chapter} chapters.

\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\end{document}
```

The first page will show

> This document has 4 chapters.

Comment: Can you use `\total{chapter}` to make arithmetic calculations?

Comment: @azetina If you define `\newcommand{\numtotal}[1]{\value{#1@totc}}` you can use `\numtotal{chapter}` (or any other registered counter) in the context of a `<number>`. The returned value is `-1` at the first run (`totcount` uses the .aux file for its workings).

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to have access to the total number of chapters per part?

Comment: @pluton This would be the subject for a new question